# Mongo replication elections, number of 'members' vs 'voting members'

Tags: mongodb, replication, database-replication

To elect a primary in an replication election, a majority of members need to be available. Does this mean majority of total `members` (including votes=0, hidden, delayed etc) or a majority of `voting members`?

What I need is a system like this

```
                     possible 
                 netw. partition
 _______    _______    |    _______    _______     _______    _______         
|   A   |  |       |   |   |   C   |  |   D   |   |   E   |  |   F   |   
|Primary|  |Arbitr.|   |   |Slave  |  |Backup |   |Backup |  |Backup |    
|_______|  |_______|   |   |_______|  |_______|   |_______|  |_______|
```

I want A to be master even in the case of possible network partition between A+Arbit. and the rest of the set. Can this be achieved? Like setting D,E,F to have `votes=0` or making them `hidden` etc?

It would be nice to have D, E and F also supporting read operations, but not absolutely necessary.

Comment: One thing, you also need a majority on one side of the paritition

Comment: In essence I need the majority to be only on the left side (A+Arb), never on right (CDEF)...

Comment: I believe the number of voting numbers will keep it there, I have to test cos I always forget (not an easy thing to remember) but you can actually have a two member set with one member down and the other primary providing you have made one member unvotable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The majority criteria is for the number of votes available within the replica set, not the number of members. Non-voting members are not included in the calculation:

> A replica set member cannot become primary unless it can connect to a majority of the members in the replica set. For the purposes of elections, a majority refers to the total number of votes, rather than the total number of members.

from http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/replica-set-elections/

so yes you should be able to do this although mongodb does recommend against it:

> IMPORTANT
>   Do not alter the number of votes to control which members will become primary. Instead, modify the priority option. Only alter the number of votes in exceptional cases. For example, to permit more than seven members.

In your diagram D, E and F can be non-voting members that still have the full data set and can be queried against for query operations.

You should be okay as long as the Primary A, the Arbiter and the Slave C are the only voting members.